# Difference between "farrago" and "gallimaufry"?

Tags: differences

What's the difference in spirit between "gallimaufry" and "farrago"? Are there any sentences where using one or the other would lead to a subtly different meaning?

Both are defined in dictionaries as "a confused mixture", or a synonym of "hotchpotch". I'm afraid they're too close to just be able to compare their dictionary definitions.

Comment: *Gallimaufry and farrago*: http://www.achehtimes.com/wordwealth/a-z/g/gallimaufry.htm

Comment: On an unrelated note, I learned two new words today.

Comment: hodgepodge, I prefer.

Comment: Compare the etymologies.

Comment: I thought for sure this question was an April Fool's joke.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Farrago** and **gallimaufry** are both colorful synonyms for an ill-assorted and mismatched collection of things - a confused assemblage of parts constituting an infelicitous whole.

The main difference is etymological: **farrago** comes from Latin, denoting mixed or varied feed.  **Gallimaufry** is from old French, suggesting an unappetizing collation of foods in an unappetizing dish - (sort of like running a week's leftovers successively through a food processor and a microwave, I suppose.)